# Currency formatting & rounding in tostring in C#

Tags: c#

I have number and I want to format in below format.

```
String num="1,124,852"
```

this to be formatted  in $1.1  M and $ 1,124 K using toString()

Comment: Show us what you attempted.

Comment: Override `ToString()`

Comment: @Amy Nice :)...

Answer (score 0):

You should use something called Format specifier as a argument to your .ToString() method call to control the number of digits produced. Combine that with some basic division and you'll get this properly printed.

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}K", specifier, (1124852m/1000).ToString("C0"));
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings